# if statement causes TpyeError: Cannont call unchain of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js

im using a if statement in my handlebars template. the if statement works, but when you try change the route it causes a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'unchain' of undefined.

i have recreated the error in the following jsbin

demo : http://emberjs.jsbin.com/UnUVorUn/9

code : http://emberjs.jsbin.com/UnUVorUn/9/edit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem happens because your `IsLink` starts with a capital letter, there was a [bug](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/fc4df510ffcd37cb185d3521c58e22881e09218d) when used in a handlebars template, already fixed in 1.3.0. But if you update your ember version you will have a new problem, because ember consider a property that starts with a capital letter being a global path, so instead of `sectionController.IsLink`, it will lookup `window.IsLink = 'teste'`.

I recommend you to just update to `isLink` to avoid these problems:

```
App.SectionController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  isLink :Ember.computed.equal('model.type', 'link')
});
```

Template

```
<ul>
  {{#link-to 'index'}} index{{/link-to}}
  {{#link-to 'test'}} test{{/link-to}}
  {{#each model itemController="section"}}
    {{#if isLink}}
      <li>{{model.color}}</li>
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/UnUVorUn/12/edit

Comment: cool should i start everything with small letters including method names ?

Comment: I think just model properties is required